# Scanner NoSuchElementException in the second iteration of while loop

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    while(true)
    {
        System.out.println("Want to repeat :");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        if(!sc.next().equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
            break;
        //Prime number
        //isPrimeNumber();

        //Fibonacci series
        //fibonacciSeries();

        //factorial using recursion
        getFactorialOfaNumber();

        sc.close();
    }
}
```

I am having this program, where every time I am checking the input from the console and based on the input provided I am deciding whether to continue or terminate the program.

For the first time it is working fine, but in the second iteration I am getting 
NoSuchElementException.

Why it is throwing an exception without asking for the input argument.

this is the console output.

```
y
FACTORIAL
Enter a number:
6
Factorial is :720
Want to repeat :
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.chandu.main.PrimeNumbers.main(PrimeNumbers.java:12)
```

Comment: You close the Scanner at each iteration. That also closes System.in. So at the second iteration, System.in is closed, and nothing can be read from it anymore.

Comment: But I am creating a new instance of scanner again. Won't it create a new instance in this case?

Comment: Read my comment again, carefully. **That also closes System.in**. **System.in is closed**. The scanner isn't closed, since you recreate it. But the stream where it reads from is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put initialization of a Scanner object outside the while loop, and also the same for the closing instruction like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(true)
    {
        System.out.println("Want to repeat :");
        if(!sc.next().equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
            break;
        //Prime number
        //isPrimeNumber();

        //Fibonacci series
        //fibonacciSeries();

        //factorial using recursion
        getFactorialOfaNumber();
    }
    sc.close();
}
```

It is not a good idea to create and close scanner every loop.  In your case you are also trying to read value from closed System.in which causes a problems

Answer (score 0):

I believe this error means that you're trying to get the `next()` element of the Scanner, when there is no next element. You can resolve this by wrapping the section with the `next()` in the following:

```
if(sc.hasNext())
```

On a side note, if the break occurs, `sc` will never close, which is bad practice. I'd recommend declaring the Scanner outside the loop, and closing it after the loop.